# Making 'For Each' loop faster

Tags: vba, excel

I have made the following code, however it takes ages to run through. I'm wondering if there may be a faster way. I want to copy the formatting (BG Color) from Range M2:M60 if it matches any cells in C2:K280. I could do conditional formatting, but as I'd need to enter 60+ items that may change was hoping I could use VBA.

```
Sub CopyColors()
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Searchrng As Range, cell As Range


Set Searchrng = Sheets("Tally").Range("M2:M60")

For Each cell In Searchrng
    For Each FoundCell In Sheets("Tally").Range("C2:K280")
        If FoundCell = cell Then
            cell.Copy
            FoundCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Else

        End If
    Next FoundCell
Next cell

Range("C2").Select

End Sub
```

-Cr1kk0

Comment: If you do a search the first thing you'll find is mention of 'disable screen updating'. Why don't you do a bit of googling.

Comment: I'm guessing with matching you mean the value, therefore you should use `FoundCell.Value = cell.Value` instead of `FoundCell = cell`.

Comment: It's your data in `M2:M60` unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should be instantaneous:

```
Sub CopyColors()

    Dim i&, j&, k&, m, n, s As Range, f As Range

    Set s = [tally!m2:m60]
    Set f = [tally!c2:k280]
    m = s.Value2
    n = f.Value2

    For k = 1 To UBound(m)
        With s(k)
            For i = 1 To UBound(n, 1)
                For j = 1 To UBound(n, 2)
                    If LenB(m(k, 1)) Then
                        If LenB(n(i, j)) Then
                            If m(k, 1) = n(i, j) Then
                                f(i, j).Interior.Color = .DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Might want to use `f(i, j).Interior.Color = s(k).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` just in case the background 'Fill' in column M is the result of conditional formatting. The [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814.aspx) will pick that up.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah, I did not choose that since OP mentioned a desire to go another route from CF... though I suppose it is possible that he was specifically referring to the left-side range.

Comment: It does actually slow things down an infinitesimal amount but that same amount can be recovered by using `m = s.Value2` instead of `m = s` (same for `n`). In any event, my comments are often designed more to educate future viewers of the solution than encouraging you to edit your answer to my way of thinking.

Comment: @Jeeped Value2 is marginally faster, only if the range includes date/time values.

Comment: Actually, I picked up 0.03 seconds with your routine with `C2:K280, M2:M280` filled with a pair of randomized upper case letters. It was pretty much the same amount that I lost when I tried it with `.DisplayFormat`. (`=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65, 90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65, 90))` then copied and paste values to generate sample data)

Comment: Which API were you using to measure?

Comment: Just `debug.print Timer`. (I didn't want to make this question a career position) :)

Comment: Understood, but I'm very confident on my position regarding Value2. To get millisecond accuracy you need to use one of the APIs:  https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-quantum-of-time/

Comment: Thank you, that worked great, now I just need to find the time to look into how it actually works compared to mine.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that working with blocks of arrays in memory would have been the quickest route but this either ties or beats the nested `For ... Next` loops through the arrays by a few milliseconds.

```
Sub Find_FindNext_Colors()
    Dim rTHIS As Range, rTHAT As Range, rTHOSE As Range

    Debug.Print Timer

    With Worksheets("Tally")
        With .Range("C2:K280, M2:M280")  '<~~in the union, M has to be same size as C:K
            For Each rTHIS In .Parent.Range("M2:M60") '<~~only M2:M60
                Set rTHAT = .Find(What:=rTHIS.Value2, After:=.Parent.Range("M60"), LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                Set rTHOSE = rTHAT
                Do While rTHAT.Column < rTHIS.Column
                    Set rTHOSE = Union(rTHOSE, rTHAT)
                    Set rTHAT = .FindNext(After:=rTHAT)
                Loop
                rTHOSE.Interior.Color = rTHIS.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
            Next rTHIS
        End With
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

I believe the scant few milliseconds are saved by assigning the [Range.Interior.Color property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499.aspx) in groups rather than individually.